# passing **kwargs to a de-referencing function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hope the title is conveying the correct information.

My problem is that I don't understand why call `kwarg_function(some_func, a=1, b=2, c=3)` fails. I would have thought that as 'c' isn't referenced with `some_func()` it would simply be ignored. Can anyone explain why 'c' isn't simply ignored.

```
def kwarg_function(function, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    function(**kwargs)

def some_func(a, b):
    print(f"type: {type(a)} values: {a}")
    print(f"type: {type(b)} values: {b}")


kwarg_function(some_func, a=1, b=2)         # called successfully

kwarg_function(some_func, a=1, b=2, c=3)    # fails with unexpected keyword arg 'c'
```

Comment: Because `kwarg_function` is in essence calling `function(..., c=3)`…

Comment: I think your confusion might come from `C++`ish background (which is nothing wrong, but the `*`, `**` have nothing in common with "referencing" per se, they are for "unpacking" iterables in this case)

Comment: @deceze thanks. I obviously hadn't thought deeply enough. I was thinking that kwargs was essentially a dictionary! However the ** means it is being unpacked, so if kwargs contains 'c' then 'c' is expected in function to which **kwargs is being passed.

Comment: `kwargs` *is* a `dict` inside `kwarg_function`; whatever mapping is used as the argument when `kwarg_function` is called is used to define a `dict`. The contents of that `dict`, though, define keyword arguments not expected by the other function you passed to `kwarg_function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the `**` as "unpack what's on my right side as keyword arguments" in this case.

```py
def foo(a,b,**kwargs):
    # This will take any number of arguments provided that starting from the 3rd one they are keyword args


# Those are equivalent (and working) calls
foo(1,2, x = 7)
foo(1,2, **{"x":7})
# Those will fail
foo(1,2,7)
foo(1,2, {"x":7})
```

The function you declared expects 2 arguments

```py
def some_func(a, b):
```

And you are calling it with three under the hood, because this:

```py
kwarg_function(some_func, a=1, b=2, c=3)    # fails with unexpected keyword arg 'c'
```

Does this (inside `kwarg_function` body):

```py
funtion(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, `*` and `**` are for unpacking iterables. They don't consider what's are in them, and just unpack whatever you pass in them.

You can find more info about it in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters#:%7E:text=In%20a%20function%20call%20the,keyword%20arguments%20into%20a%20dictionary.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on).

So, when you pass `a=1, b=2, c=3, ...` as `kwargs` to your `kwargs_function`, you will get them as `kwargs` param, regardless of what you have passed.

And then, when you pass `**kwargs` to another function, all of your data would be passed to your another function, regardless of what's in that.

If you want your `some_func` be more flexible with your data and accept whatever you pass to it, you can add `**kwargs` param to it too:

```py
def some_func(a, b, **kwargs):
    print(f"type: {type(a)} values: {a}")
    print(f"type: {type(b)} values: {b}")
```

Comment: `**` is for unpacking mappings, not iterables.